# DetailsViewDataSource dropdown with only index value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataview

I have a DetailsViewDataSource that that contains an integer that I would like to be used as the index value on a drop down list that I specify the values for. Currently when the bound data is displayed it just shows up as the number that is comming from the datasource not the text. I have tried to figure this out trying to specify the text="" as well with no difference. I feel like this should be easy but I have just been floundering.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="DetailsViewDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="MailingListId" AutoGenerateInsertButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
   <Fields>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="RefId" HeaderText="Reference Number" SortExpression="RefId" ReadOnly="true"
       />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="CallStatus" HeaderText="Call Status" ReadOnly="true"
       />
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="staqt">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList
            id="TitleDropDownList"
            runat="server"
            selectedvalue="<%# Bind('CallStatus') %>" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Item 0</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>

          </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>

       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

I have tried to access the CallStatus value on the backend. I have been able to find the row.HeaderText that matches but have not been able to find the value.

Thanks for any help that you can give me.

Comment: Can you show us the VB.NET Code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the textboxes that are generated by the detail view as a hidden storage area, that way the data binding is retained. With a jquery script I displayed the html select and the options.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.smallImage').width(400);
       var tb = $(document.getElementsByName('ctl00$MainContent$DetailsView1$ctl03')[0]);
       //console.log(tb);

       function bindcallstaus() {

           var tb = document.getElementsByName('ctl00$MainContent$DetailsView1$ctl03')[0];
           //console.log(tb);
           $(tb).hide();
           var html = '<select id="callstatus"' + '><option value="0"' + '>None</option' + '><option value="1"' + '>Claim Request</option' + '><option value="2"' + '>Contacted No Claim Request</option' + '><option value="3"' + '>Wrong Number - Working Number</option' + '><option value="4"' + '>Voicemessage Left</option' + '><option value="5"' + '>No voicemail available</option' + '><option value="6"' + '>FAQ\'s used to answer - No Claim Request</option' + '></select' + '>';
           var select = $(html);
           $(tb).parent().append(select);
           $(select).val($(tb).val());

           $(select).change(function () {
               //var tb= document.getElementsByName('ctl00$MainContent$DetailsView1$ctl01');//[0];
               var tb = document.getElementsByName('ctl00$MainContent$DetailsView1$ctl03')[0];
               //console.log($(this).val());
               $(tb).val($(this).val());
             //  console.log($(tb));
           });


       };


       $(document).ready(function () {

           bindcallstaus();

       });
   </script>
```